# Node.js Azure IoT hub mqtt error

Tags: node.js, azure, mqtt, raspberry-pi3, azure-iot-hub

I am following the Azure Microsoft tutorial to try to connect my raspberry with the IoT Platform : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-raspberry-pi-kit-node-get-started

At the last step when I run the application I have the following error :

[IoT hub Client] Connect error: mqtt.js returned premature close error

Thanks

Comment: Without any code to look at it's pretty much impossible to help here.

Comment: Works fine over here. Any restriction for 8883/TCP outbound? What happens if you switch to AMQP or HTTP?

Comment: No restriction, the port 8883 works fine when I try it with mosquitto for example. I didn't try with other protocol yet. But I notice that even when my azure iot hub device string is wrong I have the error above and no error about the string.

Comment: after changing device I have another error : Connect error : mqtt.js returned premature close error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my problem, I was using a proxy so I tried without the proxy and it works ! But I still don't know how to solve the problem using a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue([#264](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/issues/264#issuecomment-367998847)) in GitHub.Please pay attention to it.